# Perl Script to query ebay and report on items that need relisting

Tags: perl, bash

Dear all I am trying to get a script working and have no clue where to start with the error being produced

sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

My script is below and if anyone can help I would be very grateful

Tony

---

### ebay.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
system("/usr/local/bin/ebaycurl.sh");
open (ITEMS, "/usr/local/data/eBaystuff") or die "stuff $!";
while (<ITEMS>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /ViewItem\&amp/;
    s/Item not relisted/Item_not_relisted/g;
    s/Item relisted/Item_relisted/g;
    @words = split;
    $relist = "";
    foreach $word (@words) {
      if ($word =~ /ViewItem\&amp/) {
         print "\n";
         $print_it = 1;
         $link = $word;
         ($junk, $link) = split /f=/, $word;
         $link =~ s/&amp;/&/g;
         #system("/usr/local/bin/ebaycurlitem.sh $link >/dev/null 2>/dev/null");
         system("/usr/local/bin/ebaycurlitem.sh $link");
         open (ITEM, "/usr/local/data/eBayitem") or die "item $!";
         $relist = "";
         while (<ITEM>) {
            next unless /Relist/;
            $relist = 'relist';
         }
         #($junk, $itemid) = split /item=/, $link;
         #$itemid =~ s/\"//;
         print "$relist\t";
         next;
      }
      if (defined $print_it) {
         if ($word =~ /\>/) {
            $print_it = undef;
            ($rem, $junk) = split />/, $word;
            print "$rem";
         } else {
            $word =~ s/title=//;
            print "$word ";
         }
      }
      if ($word =~ /Item_not_relisted/ and $relist =~ /relist/) {print "\t\t\t\tNOT RELISTED";}
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

---

### ebaycurl.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
$(COOKIE_DIR)="cat /usr/local/etc/ebay_cookie_dir)
(/usr/bin/curl --cookie "COOKIE_DIR"/cookies.txt 'http://k2b-bulk.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SalesRecordConsole&currentpage=SCSold&ssPageName=STRK:ME:LNLK; -o /usr/local/data/eBaystuff)"
```

Comment: `cat ...dir)`? What's that `)` doing there? Plus your quotes are incorrect for the --cookie business.

Comment: Why are you trying to execute the command `COOKIE_DIR` in a subshell with `$(COOKIE_DIR)`? (I'm being facetious...I assume `COOKIE_DIR` is not actually a command) As @MarcB pointed out, there is a lot wrong with your bash syntax.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I have removed that ) and added a ' but when checking the script i get this message

Comment: Ok i have been handed the job of trying to fix this script that once did work and to be honest have not got a clue about perl so on, so any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: this was the original code used in ebaycurl.sh

Comment: #!/bin/bash
COOKIE_DIR=`cat /usr/local/etc/ebay_cookie_dir`
(/usr/bin/curl --cookie $COOKIE_DIR/cookies.txt 'http://k2b-bulk.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SalesRecordConsole&currentpage=SCSold&ssPageName=STRK:ME:LNLK' -o /usr/local/data/eBaystuff)

Comment: So... your list of ebay cookies live in a text file `cookies.txt`, and that text file lives in `/usr/local/etc/ebay_cookie_dir/`, am I right?   Also, your perl script depends on a second bash script `ebaycurlitem.sh` as well. If it's as nonsensical as the first one, you should probably post it too.

Comment: Doesn't eBay have an API for this stuff?

Comment: Cheers for the comment Dave, i have checked and there is a relevant API  for Sold Item Report's so i will have to look at how to get it to do what this script was doing, it would also be nice to fix this existing script as it was working up until the 2nd of august but since then fails to work

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot wrong with the bash script you posted. I recommend reading up on bash syntax cause it looks like you just threw parentheses and quotes in at random. Rather than explain each correction I'm just gonna post this and hope it's self-explanatory...

```
#!/bin/bash

COOKIE_DIR=$(cat /usr/local/etc/ebay_cookie_dir)

curl --cookie "$COOKIE_DIR"/cookies.txt -o /usr/local/data/eBaystuff \
    'http://k2b-bulk.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SalesRecordConsole&currentpage=SCSold&ssPageName=STRK:ME:LNLK'
```

Comment: Ok unfortunatly that's not self explanatory, I have tried using that and get the same errors. Is there anything else I can try

Comment: Ok after changing eBaycurl.pl (shown below) it now works! ,but i still get the error (sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected) when running ebay.pl ...#!/bin/bash
COOKIE_DIR=`cat /usr/local/etc/ebay_cookie_dir`
(/usr/bin/curl --cookie $COOKIE_DIR/cookies.txt 'http://k2b-bulk.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SalesRecordConsole&currentpage=SCSold&ssPageName=STRK:ME:LNLK' -o /usr/local/data/eBaystuff)

Comment: sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
relist  src="http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/pict/1611479519666464_.jpg" border="0" alt="Item picture"
relist  "Emporio Armani Classic Chrono Black Leather Mens - AR2432"
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
relist  src="http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/pict/1310443835746464_.jpg" border="0" alt="Item picture"
        "Emporio Armani - Mens Classic Black Dial Watch - AR0680"

Comment: @John Kugelman Should `"COOKIE_DIR"` in the curl line be `"$COOKIE_DIR"`?

Comment: # perl -c ebaycurl.sh
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at ebaycurl.sh line 4.
Bareword found where operator expected at ebaycurl.sh line 4, near "--cookie"
        (Missing operator before cookie?)

Comment: Operator or semicolon missing before &currentpage at ebaycurl.sh line 4.
Ambiguous use of & resolved as operator & at ebaycurl.sh line 4.
Operator or semicolon missing before &ssPageName at ebaycurl.sh line 4.
Ambiguous use of & resolved as operator & at ebaycurl.sh line 4.
Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at ebaycurl.sh line 4, near "("
syntax error at ebaycurl.sh line 4, near "("
Bad name after LNLK' at ebaycurl.sh line 4.

Comment: why are you attempting to run a bash script with perl? I was curious about why John wrote what he did, not so much suggesting you make the edit...

Comment: if i run it using bash i get # bash ./ebay.pl
./ebay.pl: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"/usr/local/bin/ebaycurl.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null"'
./ebay.pl: line 2: `system("/usr/local/bin/ebaycurl.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null");'

Comment: OK. I suggest testing each part independently. You have two bash scripts, `ebaycurl.sh` and `ebaycurlitem.sh`. To test each of those, type their names at the command prompt and hit enter. You also have `ebay.pl`, which depends on the two bash scripts. If the bash scripts are not working (as suggested by the error in your original post) then `ebay.pl` cannot work. So test the bash scripts by themselves, then test the perl script once the bash is working.

Comment: Ok many thanks, i will post the results here for you, Cheers again

Comment: perl -c ebaycurlitem.sh
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at ebaycurlitem.sh line 4.

Comment: Bareword found where operator expected at ebaycurlitem.sh line 4, near "--silent"
        (Missing operator before silent?)

Comment: Would you please update your question to include the full text of `ebaycurl.sh` and `ebaycurlitem.sh`? Are you typing `perl -c ebaycurl.sh` and hitting enter? I cannot figure out why you are getting perl errors when you run bash scripts.

Comment: Hi again @dangenet, thanks for your continued assistance sorry for the delay, i will post the contents of all three files but i am limited to how many characters i can post in a reply, i could link you to a folder with the files in though if that helps?

Comment: @user3095924 If you can edit your question (which I think you should be able to do) that would be the best way, rather than posting them in the comments. If you can't edit your own question, then go ahead and post a link. BTW, I apologize for my testiness yesterday. When debugging, though, it is very important to methodically address error messages one by one, by making deliberate changes _that you understand_ to the code. Otherwise, you are just guessing, which has infinitesmally low odds of success. I am happy to help you learn the process of troubleshooting.